# Build output doesn't match the project build order

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, build-process

I am using Visual Studio 2008 in order to build a soultion with 19 projects.

If I go to the Project Dependencies window and then to Build Order tab I see that project XXX should be the last project to be built. However, when I build the solution, project XXX is built somewhere in the middle, and it is definitely not the last project to be built.

How is this thing possible?

Comment: Why? This sounds like an XY problem.

Answer (score 1):

The Build order tab should show you one possible topological sort of the projects based on dependencies. If you want a project to always be the last one built, you should make it depend on all the other projects.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you selected another one which depends on your project XXX project before building
solution. Also, concurrent projects building at a time may cause your confusion. Let
open "Option\Projects and Solutions\Build and Run" and make sure maximum number of parallel 
projects builds is 1.

Comment: If project XXX directly or indirectly depends on all other projects (which seems to be the goal) then it will always be built on its own. Setting the number of parallel projects to 1 will slow down all other projects.